# Where can I find video Dharma talks?

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, media

I'm looking for videos with Dharma talks and am hoping that the community here can help me. Grateful for any links to online talks and DVD recommendations.

Comment: SE is a lousy place for open ended solicitations for recommendations. Some sites allow requests for highly specific literature, product or whatever recommendations.

Comment: @MatthewMartin I think that is what the "Community Wiki" mod is for... by making it a wiki, rep rewards are nullified, and multiple answers become okay. I've seen this on other SE sites, and it seems to work fine as a wiki.

Answer (score 7):

Yuttadhammo, one of the moderators on this site has done a lot of [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo) videos that people find very useful and you might too. All freely available.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question here, these are the major places i know of for the Plum Village (Thich Nhat Hanh) tradition:

- [**Plum Village Online Monastery on youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/user/plumvillageonline) Years: 2012 - present

  - [Blue Cliff Monastery channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaX_vxbhs8fgmshMksFpVsUeMfUpv8FsW)
- [**Plum Village Online Monastery on Vimeo**](https://vimeo.com/plumvillage) Years: 2010 - 2012

Also in the same tradition there are these:

- [SourceOfLightMon on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/SourceOfLightMon) (has videos overlapping with the topmost link)
- [Dharmacloud monastery on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/pvwebmonk)

Kind Regards,
Tord
PS Please edit if you know of more video resources for the PV/TNH tradition

Answer (score 4):

Here are some links you might find useful:

- *Ven. K. Sri Dhammananda*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8Sq_tAHjwk
- *Ven. Yuttadhammo*: https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo
- *Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi*: http://birken.ca/audio_collections
- *Ajahn Brahm*: https://www.youtube.com/user/AjahnBrahmRetreats/videos
- *The Dalai Lama* on Nature of the Mind*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gO7RQi55asY

Answer (score 3):

The American Zen College has a bunch of Dharma Talks videos posted up on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEsxt0ZaRw0ng6_u3aPm4EA

Answer (score 1):

Also Ven. Bodhi's Middle Length lecture series at: http://www.noblepath.org/audio.html

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend *For The Benefit of All Beings*, a film about Garchen Rinpoche

http://www.forthebenefitofallbeings.com/

May all paths lead you to the great love.

Answer (score 0):

Google video search or Youtube search: "Ask a monk" OR "Monk Radio" OR Yuttadhammo...life changing and very in harmony with the Buddha's teaching

Answer (score 0):

The "right" teacher depends on who's style and teaching you jive with.

My favorite is from the Thai Forest Tradition -- Ajahn Thanissaro

There is no fluff or BS with Ajahn Thanissaro. He calls it like it is, and challenges listeners to deeply question their practice. I appreciate this approach.

He is a westerner, studied for 20+ years in Thailand. He has videos on YouTube, but his audio talks, which he gives daily, are well worth the listen.

On top of that, he has many books. with several translations of some of Thailand's most revered Therevada Forest monks.

dhammatalks.org

Answer (score 0):

For furthering your knowledge in Buddhism please refer this link:

- http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/
- http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/dhamma-talks/

Please note these are Theravada teachings...

Answer (score 0):

Try collective teaching of Ajahn Chah.

http://www.amaravati.org/series/the-collected-teachings-of-ajahn-chah/

There are videos on youtube and also available as podcasts.

He is from thai forest tradition and is a great teacher of western monks.

Comment: Maybe you could add some links to Ajahn Chah. That would increase answer-quality.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was adding on my phone and Internet wasn't great at that time. I will add